# Change data capture (cdc) for Oracle edw

Tags: oracle-cdc

Since we can not enable CDC on Oracle database, is there any PL/SQL procedure we can write to get the changed records on daily basis? So that I can automate this script to my ADF pipeline to get the change data on daily basis.
Please help?

Comment: Why do you say you can't enable CDC on the database? CDC is the best solution anyway. It requires really to turn archivelog mode on and enable supplemental logging. Is that a problem?

Comment: What does it mean "we can not enable CDC"?

Comment: Oracle directly wont support cdc enable like in sql server. So we need to write a manual script for this, this is my understanding!

Comment: CDC is a concept. This is not a switch in the database. For Oracle the vendor of course does supports CDC. In previous versions you could achieve that using Oracle Streams features. Now you have GoldenGate but also other tools which utilise the LogMiner libraries. There are third party tools which have their own redo log parsers like Striim, Qlik, HVR but also open source OpenLogReplicator. And there is a statement in the question for not using those. Why? Please expand the question and write justification for arguments that none CDC tool could not be  used because of some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at MOVEX CDC.
https://gitlab.com/otto-group-solution-provider/movex-cdc

It is a standalone solution for CDC from Oracle-DB to Kafka.

Answer (score -1):

From my past experience I can tell you that doing it in manual/DIY way is very cumbersome.

Although there are Debezium connectors written for the same task as far as Oracle is concerned:

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/oracle.html

I have not tested it's feasibility for Oracle db per say. Debezium setup works wonderfully for MS SQL server database.

Although this do not answer your question directly. This will serve you good as a good starting path for your research.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Debezium is CDC. If the question is how to do messages without CDC. The answer can't be to use CDC.